# Conditionally select table by CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in which I am trying to conditionally select a specific table depending on a provided `tinyint` parameter. This is my code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllStuff]
    @countryId tinyint
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    DECLARE @marketSpecific TABLE

    SET @marketSpecific = 
    (CASE (@countryId)
        WHEN 1 THEN test_sv
        WHEN 2 THEN test_dk
        WHEN 3 THEN test_no
        WHEN 4 THEN test_ge
        ELSE test_sv
    END)

    [..]

END
```

Unfortunately this, does not work. I get the following errors:

> 'Must declare scalar variable @marketSpecific
>
> Invalid column name test_sv

Obviously I have misunderstood how CASE works. Can anyone provide any insight?

Comment: You can't do this I'm afraid. You could only do a set of `IF` statements like `IF @countryId = 1 SELECT * FROM test_sv ELSE IF @countryId = 2 SELECT * FRMO test_dk etc`

Comment: are test_sv, test_dk etc tables? do they have the same structure?

Comment: Yeah, the same structure. The reason I wanted to choose table conditionally was to avoid reproducing code as would be alternative with the IF/ELSE statements and since my SELECT statement is somewhat complex it would be a lot of duplicated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a dynamic query as:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllStuff]
    @countryId tinyint
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @IntVariable int
    DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500)
    DECLARE @marketSpecific varchar(100)

    /* Assign parameter value to local variable to avoid parameter sniffing */
    SET @IntVariable =  @countryId

    SET @marketSpecific = (CASE (@IntVariable)
        WHEN 1 THEN 'test_sv'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'test_dk'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'test_no'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'test_ge'
        ELSE 'test_sv'
    END)

    /* Build the SQL string one time.*/
    SET @SQLString =
     N'SELECT *
       FROM '+ @marketSpecific  


    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString 

END
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/ZGAAT57973)</kbd>

Comment: Not optimal but I guess this is probably the best solution in my case. Thank you!

Comment: Bear in mind that this means your query plans will likely be pretty inefficient.

Comment: Results from this sproc is cached anyways, it is only invoked once.

Answer (score 1):

You can't choose a table to use in a CASE statement. You could do something like this:

```
IF @countryId = 1 
    SELECT * FROM test_sv 
ELSE IF @countryId = 2
    SELECT * FROM test_dk
ELSE IF @countryId = 3
    SELECT * FROM test_no
... etc.
```

But this method might produce some odd query plans and affect performance. One alternative would be to create a view that UNIONs all the tables together (providing that have the same structure:

```
CREATE VIEW test_all
AS
SELECT 1 AS table_type, col1, col2, col3 FROM test_sv 
UNION    
SELECT 2 AS table_type, col1, col2, col3 FROM test_sdk
UNION    
SELECT 3 AS table_type, col1, col2, col3 FROM test_no
UNION    
... etc.
```

Now you can query that view in your stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllStuff]
    @countryId tinyint
AS
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM test_all WHERE table_type = @countryId
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 DECLARE @countryId      TINYINT =1,
         @sql            NVARCHAR(max),
         @marketSpecific VARCHAR(10)

SELECT @marketSpecific = CASE @countryId
                         WHEN 1 THEN 'test_sv'
                         WHEN 2 THEN 'test_dk'
                         WHEN 3 THEN 'test_no'
                         WHEN 4 THEN 'test_ge'
                         ELSE 'test_sv' END

Set @sql='select * from '+@marketSpecific

EXEC sp_excecutesql @sql
```